# php array filter duplicates where value1 and value2 is value1 and value2

Tags: arrays, duplicates, multiple-columns

i am trying to filter an array for duplicates.

currently i can filter with 1 value with:

```
$json = json_encode($inBounds);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
$nodupes = array_column($arr, Null, "limit_lat");
$count = array_count_values(array_column($arr, "limit_lat"));

foreach ($count as $key => $c){
if($c <10){
$sizeIcon= 'icon1';
}
if($c >10 && $c <100){
$sizeIcon= 'icon10';
}   
if($c >100 && $c <1000){
$sizeIcon= 'icon100';
}
if($c >1000 && $c <10000){
$sizeIcon= 'icon1000';
}   
if($c >10000){
$sizeIcon= 'icon10000';
}   

if($c === 1){   
     $nodupes[$key]['count'] = '';
     $nodupes[$key]['sizeIcon'] = $sizeIcon;
}else{
     $nodupes[$key]['count'] = $c;   
     $nodupes[$key]['sizeIcon'] = $sizeIcon;
     }
}
$nodupes = array_values($nodupes);
```

Currently i am filtering "limit_lat" but i now also need to filter "limit_lng"

So dupes should only get removed(and counted) when (limit_lat and limit_lng) is (limit_lat and limit_lng).

My json:

```
[{"id":18,"lat":"50.84757300","lng":"5.71289100","name":"Dennis","date":"2018-09-14 11:14:34","sizeIcon":"icon1","limit_lat":"51","limit_lng":"6","count":""},{"id":19,"lat":"51.06901700","lng":"-62.66601600","name":"Test","date":"2018-09-14 11:14:42","sizeIcon":"icon1","limit_lat":"51","limit_lng":"-63","count":""}]
```

Can you help me out here?
Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

got it to work with a different approach.
My $inBounds has now lat lng combined in one key.

```
$inBounds[$x]['limit'] = $row['limit_lat'].','.$row['limit_lng'];

$json = json_encode($inBounds);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
$nodupes = array_column($arr, Null, "limit");
$nodupes_lat = array_column($arr, Null, "limit");
$count = array_count_values(array_column($arr, "limit"));

foreach ($count as $key => $c){
if($c <10){
$sizeIcon= 'icon1';
}
if($c >10 && $c <100){
$sizeIcon= 'icon10';
}   
if($c >100 && $c <1000){
$sizeIcon= 'icon100';
}
if($c >1000 && $c <10000){
$sizeIcon= 'icon1000';
}   
if($c >10000){
$sizeIcon= 'icon10000';
}   

if($c === 1){   
     $nodupes[$key]['count'] = '';
     $nodupes[$key]['sizeIcon'] = $sizeIcon;
}else{
     $nodupes[$key]['count'] = $c;   
     $nodupes[$key]['sizeIcon'] = $sizeIcon;
     }
}
$nodupes = array_values($nodupes);
```